# AzureDevops Task name NuGetCommand is ambiguous

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task

I am getting the following error when trying to run my pipeline

```
Job Job: Step  task reference is invalid. The task name NuGetCommand is ambiguous. 
Specify one of the following identifiers to resolve the ambiguity: 
.NuGetCommand, .NuGetCommand
```

Below is my `.yml` file for my `.Net Standard` library

```
trigger:
- main

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

variables:
  solution: '**/MyLibrary.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'
steps:
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@1
- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    command: 'restore'
    restoreSolution: '**/MyLibrary.sln'
    feedsToUse: 'config'
    nugetConfigPath: './nuget.config'

- task: VSBuild@1
  inputs:
    solution: '**\MyLibrary.sln'
    vsVersion: '15.0'
    restoreNugetPackages: true
```

It seems to be complaining about `NugetCommand@2` which doesn't make sense when it comes built in?

**Edit**
Have also tried using `- task: 333b11bd-d341-40d9-afcf-b32d5ce6f23b@2` instead of `- task: NuGetCommand@2`

Comment: Hi there, are there any updates for this question? Please check whether jessehouwing's comments can help you and feel free to comment.

Answer (score 0):

One may have been pushed straight into the account using `tfx build tasks upload`, run `tfx build tasks list` to find out which ones are installed and if needed delete the non-official one using `tfx build tasks delete`.

```
C:\Users\jesse>npm install tfx-cli -g
C:\Users\jesse>tfx build tasks list
TFS Cross Platform Command Line Interface v0.8.3
Copyright Microsoft Corporation
> Service URL: https://dev.azure.com/jessehouwing-dev
> Personal access token:
```

The one you want to keep is:

```
id            : 333b11bd-d341-40d9-afcf-b32d5ce6f23b
name          : NuGetCommand
friendly name : NuGet
visibility    :
description   : Restore, pack, or push NuGet packages, or run a NuGet command. Supports NuGet.org and authenticated feeds like Azure Artifacts and MyGet. Uses NuGet.exe and works with .NET Framework apps. For .NET Core and .NET Standard apps, use the .NET Core task.
version       : 2.179.0
```

If there is one with a different guid, delete is with:

```
C:\Users\jesse>tfx build tasks delete --task-id the-task-id-guid-to-delete
```

It may also have been pushed as part of a privately shared custom extension. The marketplace will block tasks with the rame GUID, but it will allow installing a task with the same name just fine through an extension. Check your installed extensions, especially privately shared ones.

Comment: Thanks for the fast response.

I saw also [this link](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/1267634/duplicate-task-issue-with-nugetcommand-in-microsof.html) which uses the same ID you mentioned of `333b11bd-d341-40d9-afcf-b32d5ce6f23b`.

Would my new task look something like

```
- task: 333b11bd-d341-40d9-afcf-b32d5ce6f23b@2
  inputs:
    command: 'restore'
    restoreSolution: '**/MyLibrary.sln'
    feedsToUse: 'config'
    nugetConfigPath: './nuget.config'
```
I am running into a "String does not match the pattern of "^DataDeployTriggerTask@1$".

Comment: @mikeg I tried to use `333b11bd-d341-40d9-afcf-b32d5ce6f23b@2` instead of - `NuGetCommand@2` and it worked successfully. Could you please edit your question and give a more detailed error message? Is it running failed with error message or is it not running at all?

Comment: When I try `333b11bd-d341-40d9-afcf-b32d5ce6f23b@2`

I get this error message `String does not match the pattern of "^DataDeployTriggerTask@1$".`

Comment: That's a weird error... Can you share the diagnostics logs anywhere for the whole job? Or share them privately? It looks like your organisation may have installed global YAML templates...

Comment: So what do you see when you run `tfx build tasks list`?

Answer (score 0):

> AzureDevops Task name NuGetCommand is ambiguous

According to the error message, it seems that error can happen when two tasks\extensions exist in your Azure DevOps organization with the same name.

You could use this REST API:

```
https://dev.azure.com/{organisationName}/_apis/distributedtask/tasks?visibility%5B%5D=Build
```

to check here for possible duplicates.

To resolve this issue, you could use command line to invoke nuget.exe to restore the solution:

```
nuget.exe restore a.sln -source "xx" -PackagesDirectory
```